Edit button on old revision doesn't edit right revision
I was on staging ground. I checked revision history, and I would like to get the text from some specific revision (not the actual one). So I clicked on the button "Edit this revision", and it opened the edition of the actual post...
My case is this revision list while trying to edit the revision 2 (to get the code), but it doesn't open the right revision.
I think it's not normal, so is that possible to fix this bug?

All revision edit links have a UID in the link which is normal. However, all 3 revision edit links just edit the current version of the post. This seems to only happen on the Staging Ground - main questions behave normally.
